# JS Regex for email allowing asterisk

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a JS Regex which checks the validity of an email address. It all works good, however lately i noticed that it allows an asterisk `*` as a valid part of the email. I know some users maybe using that i don't want my application to allow that.

So far the code is :

```
  RegExp = /^((([a-z]|[0-9]|!|#|$|%|&|'|\*|\+|\-|\/|=|\?|\^|_|`|\{|\||\}|~)+(\.([a-z]|[0-9]|!|#|$|%|&|'|\*|\+|\-|\/|=|\?|\^|_|`|\{|\||\}|~)+)*)@((((([a-z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[0-9]|\-){0,61}([a-z]|[0-9])\.))*([a-z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[0-9]|\-){0,61}([a-z]|[0-9])\.)[\w]{2,4}|(((([0-9]){1,3}\.){3}([0-9]){1,3}))|(\[((([0-9]){1,3}\.){3}([0-9]){1,3})\])))$/
```

Kindly, advise how to change this so that `*` becomes an invalid character in the email provided by users.

Comment: Why don't you want your application to allow that?

Comment: actually, mine is a college administration app where data was read from scanned OMR sheets and thing about that OMR software was that it read empty circles as `*`, therefore most of users' emails are with that and hence wrong. Now, when they edit that, i want to avoid this problem..

Comment: OK that's valid :) through experience, most people just want to limit the user's allowed email formats, hence why I asked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove the escaped asterisks from your regex. Then your regex would become:

```
 RegExp = /^((([a-z]|[0-9]|!|#|$|%|&|'|\+|\-|\/|=|\?|\^|_|`|\{|\||\}|~)+(\.([a-z]|[0-9]|!|#|$|%|&|'|\+|\-|\/|=|\?|\^|_|`|\{|\||\}|~)+)*)@((((([a-z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[0-9]|\-){0,61}([a-z]|[0-9])\.))*([a-z]|[0-9])([a-z]|[0-9]|\-){0,61}([a-z]|[0-9])\.)[\w]{2,4}|(((([0-9]){1,3}\.){3}([0-9]){1,3}))|(\[((([0-9]){1,3}\.){3}([0-9]){1,3})\])))$/
```

[EDIT]

Don't remove **all** asterisks. Remove only the *escaped* asterisks.